# footnote for an item in tablenotes

Tags: tables, footnotes, tablenotes

I would like to have a footnote for an item in tablenotes. The following code does not show the footnote (http://example.org) in the bottom of the page and is not received any error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!ht]
    \centering
    \small
    \caption{Example}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l} \toprule
        A & B & C\tnote{1} \\
        D & E & F\\ \toprule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[1]This is test\footnote{\url{http://example.org}}.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \label{tb:test}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Completing your snippet, I have no problem, except  for a ‘Unicode Character not set up for use with LaTeX’. Could you post a *complete* code reproducing the problem?

Comment: I updated the code and question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `tablefootnote` package, which is for footnotes inside tables, doesn't work inside `tablenotes`.  So I propose as a work-around to use the pair `\footnotemark` …`\footnotetext`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!ht]
    \centering
    \small
    \caption{Example}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l} \toprule
        A & B & C\tnote{1} \\
        D & E & F\\ \toprule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[1]This is test\footnotemark.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \label{tb:test}
\end{table*}
\footnotetext{\url{http://example.org}}.

\end{document}
```

[image]